# Eggs fried/scrambled "over easy" or "over hard" — refers to the pan, the egg, or something else?

Tags: expressions

To me, "over easy" seems to refer to the pan, because I think of a pan sitting atop an easy flame.  "Over hard" makes me think it refers to the egg, because the liquid becomes solid.  Then again, maybe it's something else altogether.

Comment: I think _hard_ refers to the yolk, as you surmise, but then _easy_ is just the opposite of _hard_. I guess _over but still retaining its liquid form_ just didn't sound quite right.

Answer (score 6):

There's not really such a thing as *over easy* scrambled eggs. It originates with fried eggs, where it means turn them over *gently* (easy, carefully) and cook for for a few seconds more before serving, so the white is fully set (not "snotty"). That's *gently* because you don't want to break the yolk.

The opposite to *over easy* is *sunny side up* (i.e. - *don't* do that turning over).

EDIT: Because *over easy* is so well-known in the above context, and because there are no other standard terms to describe how you want your eggs (unlike, say, *rare, medium, bloody, well-done* for steaks), people do sometimes extrapolate variants such as *over hard*, or apply *over easy* to scrambled eggs. They're easily understood, but such usages aren't really standard terminology.

---

EDIT2: It never occurred to me anyone would propose an alternative origin for *over easy*. Having scoured the Internet, I don't see anything looking remotely like an "authoritative" etymological reference - so unless someone else does, all I can offer is a couple of links supporting what I think...

> 1. The spatula edge should stay on the pan so that the rolling of the egg off the spatula is "[easy](http://www.ehow.com/how_2051043_fry-egg-over-easy.html#page=0)".
> 2. ...in order to faciliate lightly cooking the yolk, you would have to flip the eggs over, and to prevent the yolk from breaking (and rendering the eggs "cooked hard") you have to flip them over [easy](http://ask.metafilter.com/6002/eggs-over-I-can-understand-over-easy-though-is-hard).

Comment: Actually a colleague with a heart transplant needed to order eggs over "hard" because no part of the fried egg could be under cooked - though I'm sure that phrase would be exceedingly rare.

Comment: @Kristina: Bearing in mind your culinary credentials, I'm diffident about disagreeing, but I'd be surprised if the doctor wrote *Any fried eggs must be over hard* on his "special needs" diet card. *Thoroughly cooked through*, or maybe just *fully cooked* sounds more credible there.

Comment: Well, I admit that I know next to nothing as regards culinary skills, but I do eat at a lot of diners and I hear "scrambled over easy" all the time.  Not saying its right, but it is common.

Comment: I'm pretty sure *over medium* and *over hard* are recognized terms: they all mean that the egg should be fried on both sides, but cooked more than *over easy*.  An egg cooked *over easy* will have a fully cooked white but a runny yolk, when *over medium* the yolk is mostly congealed, and when *over hard* the yolk is completely solid.  I've ordered eggs both ways in restaurants (in the US) and never been asked to clarify.  It's neither exceedingly rare nor facetious, just not as popular among diners.  Google has lots of hits for both.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, my explanation was lacking clarity. I believe "over hard" was her expression, not the doctor's orders. :-)

Comment: @Fred: That thought did occur to me after I'd posted. I think the thing is there's not really a standard term for it in relation to scrambled eggs - you'd certainly get some funny looks in the average diner if you asked for yours to be cooked [a pointe](http://quizlet.com/11957310/french-food-terms-flash-cards/)! Perhaps I'd better edit that in.

Comment: For scrambled eggs, you just drop the *over*. That's how I order mine anyway: "Eggs scrambled hard." I've never had a server ask me what I meant and I usually get them the way I wanted them, so I assume it's standard lingo.

Comment: Fumble, you should update your answer with the standard terminology that Nate explains. Or this should rather be a question for people who actually know at cooking.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Mitch: The question is drifting well beyond its original scope, which was to explain the reason why we use the words *over easy*. I'm saying it's because you turn them over "easy" with a spatula, Kate says it's derived from an earlier "hard" [-cooked yolk], and Kaz says it's from an *easy=soft/gentle* heat source. Vote on that, and leave the recipes and related specialised terminology to other questions and/or other sites.

Comment: I'm disinclined to accept without a cite that _over easy_ predates _over hard_ and not vice versa (or simultaneous), perhaps because I prefer the latter.

Comment: @Andrew: It's what I've always understood, but it's never occurred to me to seek "authoritative" confirmation of that origin. Perhaps I might now (or perhaps someone else will). Vote or don't vote as you please - in the unlikely event a credible source convinces me I'm wrong, I'll delete this answer.

Comment: ... [this](http://ask.metafilter.com/6002/eggs-over-I-can-understand-over-easy-though-is-hard) isn't a credible source, but since I believe *"in order to faciliate lightly cooking the yolk, you would have to flip the eggs over, and to prevent the yolk from breaking (and rendering the eggs "cooked hard") you have to flip them over **easy**"* is correct, there's the link.

Comment: @Fumble: thought oughtta be an answer (or, in this case, edited into your answer).

Comment: I've been ordering "eggs over hard, broken" for around 50 years in the U.S. The cook knows what it means.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that "over hard" came first: it's [diner jargon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diner_lingo) that the eggs should be flipped **over** and cooked until they are **hard**. Now if you want it flipped but not hard, well the opposite of hard is **easy**, right? (Sure, you could say soft or runny, but diner slang is often supposed to be funny, a bit of an in-joke, and opaque.)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, *easy* refers to going easy on the temperature and duration, and hard on the condition of the egg, as you suspect. We can play hard and work hard, but we don't really speak about cooking hard. The egg yolk gets solidifies atop even an easy flame, given enough time. And of course, *easy* doesn't refer to the liquid condition of the yolk.

Answer (score 0):

These terms refer to the egg, namely to its degree of cooked-ness: *over-easy* is cooked on both sides but yolk is runny; *over-medium* is less runny than over-easy, and *over-hard* is when both the yolk and white is cooked all the way through.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, yet your submission does not attempt to answer the question.  I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.